# How to add tag inside a nest depending on a variable while keeping rest of json

Tags: json, jq

I'm failry new to jq and I've learned to do most things on my own but I'm hitting my head on my keyboard for this one.   Look at the following json

JSON:

```
  {
  "importType": "Upsert",
  "immediateDeployment": false,
  "isIgnoreNulls": false,
  "isOverwriteNullsOnly": false,
  "isPreferredandSync": false,
  "outputLayout": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "TEMP_KEY",
        "type": "String",
        "length": "2000",
        "displayName": "TEMP_KEY"
      },
      {
        "name": "LoadSeqNum",
        "type": "String",
        "length": "2000",
        "displayName": "LoadSeqNum"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is inside of .outputLayout.fields[] I want to create a new pair called "isIdentifier" where it is true if the .outputLayout.fields[].name is LoadSeqNum and false if it's not but I need to keep the rest of the json just as it is.  So target should look as following:

Goal:

```
  {
  "importType": "Upsert",
  "immediateDeployment": false,
  "isIgnoreNulls": false,
  "isOverwriteNullsOnly": false,
  "isPreferredandSync": false,
  "outputLayout": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "TEMP_KEY",
        "type": "String",
        "length": "2000",
        "displayName": "TEMP_KEY"
        "isIdentifier": false
      },
      {
        "name": "LoadSeqNum",
        "type": "String",
        "length": "2000",
        "displayName": "LoadSeqNum"
        "isIdentifier": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
jq '.outputLayout.fields[] | . + {"isIdentifier": (if (.name)=="LoadSeqNum" then true else false end)}'
```

But of course I'm missing all the higher level things.  When I try to do:

```
.outputLayout.fields[].isIdentifier=(if (.outputLayout.fields[].name)=="LoadSeqNum" then true else false end)
```

I get the whole thing twice, once with both true and the other one with both false.  I understand why it's doing that but I'm having a tough time figuring out what would work.  Any help or point in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.outputLayout.fields[] |= (.isIdentifier = (.displayName == "LoadSeqNum") )
```

Or equivalently but perhaps a little less cryptically:

```
.outputLayout.fields |= map( .isIdentifier = (.displayName == "LoadSeqNum") )
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly.  I understand most of what's going on there except for the |= operator.  I've read the manual but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: `.foo |= expr` is like the assignment `.foo = (.foo|expr)` but more complex path expressions can be used than simply ".foo".